# Adicionar espaço entre palavras em Python

Tags: python-3.x

Estou trabalhando NLP e analise e tenho alguns problemas de junção de palavras ao extrair o texto de um documento, como por exemplo:

1. C Programming LanguageSecurity Engineering
2. Cloud ComputingDOMAIN
3. ComputingDigital MarketingProduct
4. Data ScienceFields
5. DataVisualizationStatisticalProgramming

Em todos exemplos as junções são realizadas com uma letra minúscula e uma letra maiúscula, como posso adicionar um espaço utilizando Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar regex. Você substitui a letra minúscula seguida da maiúscula e reinclui as letras com um espaço entre elas. Exemplificando:

```
import re

txt = "C Programming LanguageSecurity Engineering"

x = re.sub(r"([a-z])([A-Z])", r"\1 \2", txt)
print(x)

# C Programming Language Security Engineering
```